# How to specify (import?) scheme in GraphQL in python (graphene?)?

Tags: python, graphql, web-api-testing, graphene-python, graphql-java

shame to ask, but we have GraphQL Server on Java (https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-spring-boot), where we specified type.graphqls scheme for our service.
On client side we have JS code based on Apollo Client library. And it does not need acess to this types file.
But days are come and I need to write some API tests.  Most people in our team speaks Python very well, so I decided to make test workbench on python, but I cant't find any library that let me write queries schema-free or import my types.graphqls scheme.
How can I write tests on python for custom GraphQL server thogh?
Thanks!

Comment: The client (or tests) never actually need access to your schema definition files. All the info can be obtained via introspection, and that is what all libraries normally do.

Comment: introspection? Can you provide some links please?

Comment: Check [here](http://graphql.org/learn/introspection/). The client can get all the info that way. And most libraries provide a way to convert the introspection result into SDL for human readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a gist with simple GraphQL client based on requests library:

```
import requests

def run_query(query, variables):
    request = requests.post('https://dev.darkdata.finance:9000/graphql',
                        json={'query': query, 'variables': variables})

    if request.status_code == 200:
        return request.json()
    else:
        raise Exception("Query failed to run by returning code of {}. {}".format(request.status_code, query))
```

You can use it to test simple queries if you want.
Source: https://gist.github.com/gbaman/b3137e18c739e0cf98539bf4ec4366ad